# Converting function to es6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am working on learning how to use es6 `class` and need some help in understanding how this would be converted from a `function` to a `class`:

```
function MyModel(make, year) {
    var carType = this;

    carType.make = make;

    // function that I have further in code
    sellCar(carType, year);
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
class MyModel {
  constructor(make, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.year = year;

    sellCar(this.make, this.year);
  }
}
```

What I get confused about is what I do about the reference I have to `this` that I reference from the variable. Do I need that? I use that in other parts of my code, but would rather refactor to not do so.

The sticky point for me right now is assigning `this` to carType. If I put the code below in my `constructor`, how do I point a reference to `this` from `carType`?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  make and year are most likely memeber variables, sellCar likely a method (although I would argue probably doesnt belong as a method inside of the class rather something that acts on an Object of that class).

Comment: Read this, will help you slot, update m me if future assistant needed, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: You can just use `class MyModel { constructor(make, year) { /* same function body here */ }}`. No need to convert variables to properties.

Comment: @akaphenom Please see EDIT and let me know if that helps you understand my confusion a bit. Just trying to get to a point where I understand if it makes sense to reassign this to a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original code is needlessly complicated and doesn't make sense

```
function MyModel(make, year) {
    var carType = this;

    carType.make = make;

    // function that I have further in code
    sellCar(carType, year);
}
```

It could be written as

```
function MyModel(make, year) {
  this.make = make;
  sellCar(this, year);
}
```

In ES6, it's a trivial transform

```
class MyModel {
  constructor (make, year) {
    this.make = make;
    sellCar(this, year);
  }
}
```

ES6 `class`es are just syntactic sugar, so the functionality is going to be identical (provided you always invoke the constructor with the `new` keyword (which you should))

But what is `sellCar`? The return value is discarded so I have to believe that `sellCar` has some other kind of side effect.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had needless code in there and that is what was probably the issue with my confusion.

Comment: Sorry, the `sellCar()` was part of my function and just added to the prototype that initialized methods.